Opening an existing node
I have my Node class (class AbstractController(ABC, Node)) launched by the launch file and that creates the Node of my app in order to get the parameters. However, for the communication (publisher/subscriber), I want to do it in another class. Indeed, I want the user to be able to choose the communication method (ROS, ZMQ...) as a launch parameter. Then, I created a class class AbstractInterface(ABC) to send the message according to the method. In the ROS interface I would be able to get the Node I launched in the AbstractController:
class RosInterface(AbstractInterface, Node):
    def __init__(self, caller_name: str):
        super().__init__(interface_name="ROS", # The name of the interface (AbstractInterface attribute)
                         caller_name=caller_name, # The name of the caller (AbstractInterface attribute)
                         node_name=caller_name # The name of the ROS node (Node attribute)
                        )

But here it will create a new Node with the same name, creating conflicts. Is there a way to open an existing node?
Here is the begining of the constructor of the AbstractController:
communication_interface: AbstractInterface

def __init__(self, robot_name) -> None:
        self.ROBOT_NAME = robot_name      
        super().__init__(node_name=self.ROBOT_NAME+'_controller')        

        self.get_logger().info("========= "+self.ROBOT_NAME+" CONTROLLER =========")   
        self.declare_parameter('communication_interface', "ros")
        communication_interface = self.get_parameter('communication_interface').get_parameter_value().string_value
        CommunicationInterfaceClass = globals()[communication_interface.capitalize()+'Interface']
        self.communication_interface = CommunicationInterfaceClass(self.ROBOT_NAME+'_controller')

